# Can terminal window titles be updated while a process is running?

Tags: bash, gui, xterm

I'm trying to set a little pomodoro/countdown timer for myself in the terminal.

[This comment](https://superuser.com/a/612483/444076) on Superuser offers a handy little shell function that will act as a countdown timer, which `printf`s the remaining time to STDOUT (awesome). I was thinking it would be even better if I could see the live countdown in the title of that terminal emulator tab, so I could monitor my remaining time without having to switch back and forth between tabs.

It appears [the `PROMPT_COMMAND` environment variable can be used to update the window title](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Xterm-Title-4.html#ss4.3), but since its contents are executed [only just before Bash displays a prompt](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/x264.html), there's no way it can live update the title while the process is running (that I know of).

Is there any way this can be done?

(It has occurred to me that I could solve this more easily by splitting a new pane in tmux, but I'm on a small screen, and I'd appreciate being able to save all the screen real estate I can.)

Comment: Just output the ANSI codes to stdout or stderr. Some terminals might also provide API to change their titles programmatically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Terminal codes might be what you need, see http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/terminalcodes and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code for details (or http://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html for quite a technical description of the the codes relating to xterm).

Here an example of how to set the title:

```
set_title() {
  printf '\033]0;%s\007' "$*"
}
```

Comment: Holy crap you're a genius. Shame I can't upvote yet.

Answer (score 2):

Just output the relevant ANSI codes to stdout or stderr.

The following works for me in an `xterm`:

```
for i in {10..1} ; do printf '\e]0;'$i'\a' ; sleep 1 ; done &
```

Some terminals might also provide API to change their titles programmatically.